# Substitute of "occursin" function to find a string in an Array{String,1}

Tags: julia

What I am trying to do is

```
i = occursin("ENTITIES\n", lines)
i != 0 || error("ENTITIES section not found")
```

The error information is

```
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching occursin(::String, ::Array{String,1})
Closest candidates are:
  occursin(::Union{AbstractChar, AbstractString}, ::AbstractString) at strings/search.jl:452
```

This is a piece of julia v0.6 code. I am using v1.1 now. I am new to julia and don't know what's the proper subsititute function for this. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can broadcast `orrursin` like this (add a `.` after function name):

```
julia> x = "abc"
"abc"

julia> y = ["abc", "xyz"]
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "abc"
 "xyz"

julia> b = occursin.(x, y)
2-element BitArray{1}:
  true
 false

julia> findall(b)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> findfirst(b)
1
```

Note that although `String` can be iterated over it is treated by broadcast as a scalar.

Also it is worth to remember that `occursin` returns `Bool` value so that you can use it directly in logical tests e.g. `i || error("ENTITIES section not found")` in the code from your question.

In order to locate the index in the collection of the occurrence of `true` in the return value of broadcasted `occursin` use `findall` or `findfirst` functions (there is also `findlast`). The difference is that `findall` returns a vector of entries where `true` is encountered in the collection, while `findfirst` returns the first such entry only. Also note the difference when you pass all `falses` to it. `findall` will return an empty vector and `findfirst` will return `nothing`.

If you do not want to retain the vector `b` in the code above, you can get the indices directly (this should be faster) by passing a predicate as a first argument to `findall`/`findfirst`:

```
julia> findall(t -> occursin(x, t), y)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> findfirst(t -> occursin(x, t), y)
1
```

Comment: Hi Bogumił, thanks for your help! But I need the index of the string in the array. Is there any way to do so?